# PHP - Print Labels Server Side

Tags: php, pdf, printing, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to print label sized documents to a label printer server-side, so the web app can be used on mobile devices.

So far I have tried the following:

- Generating .docx file with OpenTBS and using WatchDirectory to print the files as they come into the folder. - Works well and generates the files well, however the WatchDirectory program does not reliably print out the documents.
- Printing .docx from PHP using *exec* to run command line option 'print' - doesn't work as it must be printed through Microsoft Word.
- I've also looked at solutions such as SilentPrint (£60 for 2 printers or something like £300 for 20 printers, too much unfortunately for us to spend).

I'm looking for a easy way to do server-side silent printing. Ideally without it opening the program to print. The other thing I thought would work is if I can somehow generate a label sized PDF document, I can then use *exec* in PHP to run a java program to print it - the java program works, but I haven't found a way to generate the PDF from PHP.

Things that might help me:

- A way to generate PDF files from PHP with specific dimensions / margins.
- A reliable way to print word documents from PHP, or software to print it once it's been generated.
- A command line docx to pdf converter without the need to open MS Word.
- Anything else!

If anyone has any suggestions on how this can be done, I'd be very grateful.

---

I may have found the answer using FPDF as mentioned below. Instead of generating the file as a docx, I've generated the PDF using FPDF and can them try printing from command line silently using the Java application. If it works, I'll post the details here:

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');

    $txt = "Good work Ben!";
    $pdf = new FPDF( 'P', 'mm', array(41, 88) );
    $pdf->SetMargins( 4.5, 4.5 );
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak( true, 4.5 );
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->MultiCell(0,3.8,$txt,0,'L');
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this, I must have opened this tab earlier and never looking at it. http://www.fpdf.org/

Will give this a go and see if it does what I want. If I find a way to do this, I'll post the answer here, but any other suggestions are welcome. Have been searching for ages for a way to do what I need, and I know others are in a similar position!

Comment: Did it work with the silent Java call?